# Meaning of って followed by のが?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, nominalization, particle-って

In the sentence

> 殺さずに生け捕るってのが面倒でしたがね

is the って being used as quoting? Does this change the function of のが?

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same meaning

> 殺さずに生け捕るってのが面倒でしたがね
>
> 殺さずに生け捕るのが面倒でしたがね

the って is a abbreviation of という which is emphasizing 殺さずに生け捕る.